# opencv warpaffine negative translation

Tags: opencv

I am attempting to use OpenCVs warpAffine to transform an image with a simple translation. The image produced from a negative versus positive translation surprises me.

```
from skimage import data
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pylab import *

ion()
fig = figure()
fig.clear()
image = data.camera()

# positive translation
rigid0 = np.float32([[1.0, 0.0, 96.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]])
w0 = cv2.warpAffine(image,rigid0,(image.shape[1]+int(abs(rigid0[0,2])),image.shape[0]))

# negative translation 
rigid1 = np.float32([[1.0, 0.0, -96.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]])
w1 = cv2.warpAffine(image,rigid1,(image.shape[1]+int(abs(rigid1[0,2])),image.shape[0]))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(w0, cmap=gray())

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
imshow(w1, cmap=gray())
```

I have inserted the produced figure below, notice how the negative translation on the right appears to eat twice as many pixels off the image. Both images are construced with a translation by 96 pixels, one negative and the other positive.

[image: positive versus negative translation]

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to reproduce your output in c++:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("H:/cameraman.jpg");
  cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(512, 512));

  cv::Mat rigid0 = (cv::Mat_<double>(2, 3) << 1., 0., 96.,
                                              0., 1., 0.);


  cv::Mat rigid1 = (cv::Mat_<double>(2, 3) << 1., 0., -96.,
                                              0., 1., 0.);

  cv::Mat res0, res1;

  cv::warpAffine(img, res0, rigid0, cv::Size(img.cols + 96., img.rows));
  cv::warpAffine(img, res1, rigid1, cv::Size(img.cols + 96., img.rows));

  cv::imshow("0", res0);
  cv::imshow("1", res1);
  cv::waitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

According to the documentation of [warpAffine function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#void%20warpAffine(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)), the resulting image is constructed by:

```
dst(x, y) = src(M11 * x + M12 * y + M13, M21 * x + M22 * y + M23)
```

where M is an invertion of your affine matrix. So in case of negative translation, you have:

```
dst(x, y) = src(x + 96, y)
```

So, it is exactly what you have (input shifted by 96 pixels left).

You set resulting size wider for 96 pixels, so the resulting image is filled with black according to the **borderMode** and **borderValue** default values (which are **BORDER_CONSTANT** with black color).

UPDATED:

in case you still not understand what's going on, I have made a picture for you:

[image: eating cameraman]

Comment: Not sure if this explains why the negative translation eats 2x96 pixels, where as positive eats 1x96?

Comment: Negative translation "eats" exactly 1x96 pixels, too. Other 96 pixels "are eaten" by the fact that you set up the size of the final image by 96 pixels wider than original one. This rightmost 96 columns are filled in black color by default (please, read carefully the last sentence of my answer)